# Ignore additional JSON field while getting the POST request from HTTP client

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-rest

I am working on a Spring REST application. I have a rest controller having the function like below.

```
@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.POST)
public ResponseEntity<Map<String, String>> saveProfileEntry(@RequestBody ProfileEntry entry) {
  //
}
```

For the above router, If I post exactly similar or less number of fields as in `ProfileEntry` POJO using it is passes. If I have additional fields in my posted JSON then the request fails and generate following error.

> HTTP Status [Bad Request]
>   The server cannot or will not process
>   the request due to something that is perceived to be a client error
>   (e.g., malformed request syntax, invalid request message framing, or
>   deceptive request routing).

How can I avoid this exception while my client could send additional data that is not available in my POJO?

Answer (score 2):

I was able to solve it by adding the following to my servlet configuration and annotating the POJO to ignore the unknown properties.

**Servelet Config**

```
    <bean id="jacksonMessageConverter"
    class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter"></bean>
    <bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter">
        <property name="messageConverters">
            <list>
                <ref bean="jacksonMessageConverter" />
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

**Annotation for POJO**

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown=true)
```

This worked for me.